# Spring Controllers logic

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a question connected to Spring REST and controllers. 
I create football application. My application has clubs and players in database. I have an API RestController for clubs and API RestController for Players. 
Is it a good way to add  players to club in club's controller or I should do this in player's controller or it doesn't matter? Which is a better way?
For example, in my club's controller I have some CRUD methods for clubs and I created methods to get/add players from/to club by club id, get/add player by id for club, etc. Is it ok or should it be in player's controller? 
In general, how to think about this controllers logic - how to separate connected part of application?

Answer (score 0):

You should not access database directly from controllers. Controllers should be your presentation layer, and those crud methods should be tied to repository which is used by service.

@Controller - accept HTTP request and activate service

@Service - for your business logic

@Repository - data access logic

So, you should use @Controller to pass data to @Service which offers higher level abstraction over your @Respository CRUD operations.

Added spring reference for more detailed explanation:

@Repository
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html

@Service
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html

Regarding the player - club relationship:
many to one and one to many are in fact same relationship from a different viewpoint, both approaches are technically  correct. Decide for whichever makes more semantic sense to you.